# Is the word order correct in my sentence?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, word-order

Could you please tell me if the word order in this sentence is correct or not?

Olga sat in a comfortable armchair cross-legged, enjoying her deception the same way she had been on too many occasions before.

Comment: The order of which words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Olga sat cross-legged on a comfortable armchair, enjoying her deception the same way she had on many occasions before."

I think this sounds more natural.  Try not to seperate adverbs so much from their antecedents.

Comment: Correction. Your adverb is not an antecedent to the verb "sat".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the existing answer, but since this is creative writing (is it not?) you could keep cross-legged where you have it. Poetry and fiction allow for flexibility in cases like that, besides which in speech one might split "sat" and "cross-legged", almost as if cross-legged came as an afterthought. 
As far as dropping "been", you should in this case because "enjoy" is a transitive verb (it is something that you "do" to another thing). "Olga was enjoying her deception as she had **done** ... before."

I wouldn't be surprised if there exists a usage guide somewhere that contradicts me on this but I believe that people don't use either "had been" or "had done" particularly often, preferring just "had", but if you do want to include the verb "had" modifies, in this case it would be "done".

Comment: I am surprised that one thinks "had been" or "had done" are not used particularly often. I use them quite a bit. I'm not sure the last paragraph is needed here.